# Can we use Paint Component without extending JPanel Class?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm making a gui in which draw a line using paint component method i know i can do that with extends JPanel. But i really want to know how to do this without extending anything.Like in this program

```
public class Main {

    static JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Our Frame");
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setSize(600,480);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(panel);
    }
}
```

And on this Way

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame obj = new Frame();
    }
        }
```

### The frame

```
 public class Frame extends JFrame{

    private JPanel panel;

    public Frame(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        setSize(600,480);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        add(panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first question is "why"?

Comment: The second question is "how?". More precisely: *Where* should the actual painting take place? There are several libraries that try to achieve goals like this. They offer classes where you can call something like `myDrawingSurface.drawCircle(x,y,r);` and the drawings "magically" appear on the screen. But these are only abstraction layers (usually, for novice programmers), and they are just hiding some of the "complexities" (e.g. they *internally* still use classes that extend `JPanel` and do the actual painting in the `paintComponent` method)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(true) {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                // do painting
            }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, *technically* you can use `component.getGraphics();` to get the graphics context for a given component, then draw on that. **But** since the component will also repaint itself, your drawing will **vanish** as soon as the repaint occurs. So don't even think about doing that, you will only waste your time!

However if you have a component that renders a `BufferedImage` in `paintComponent()`, you can draw on the image (with `img.getGraphics();` etc.) and the component will then reflect those drawings. This will allow you to have a simple `MyPanel` class, where `paintComponent()` will only draw the image. You can then get a reference to the image, and draw on that from whereever you want.

You're already extending something in your code, and in your case it's completely unnecessary. You can remove your `Frame` class and display a `JFrame` with the following code.

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setSize(600, 480);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.add(panel);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: While technically you can, you never should, because what every you paint to it will be replaced when the component is repainted by the system...`getGraphics`, put simply, is NEVER a viable solution

Comment: Well.. isn't that what I said?

Comment: In which case, I would never mention it to unwary developers, they read the first paragraph and ignore the rest ;)

Comment: We need some sort of warning tags or red colour to mark scary things.

Comment: @MadProgrammer There, I tried to make it look more menacing.

Comment: @Kayaman Does you mean when we extend with JPanel and use paint component then it automatically repaint

Comment: @JohnDoe When a repaint occurs, all components are told to draw themselves, so all visible components' `paintComponent(Graphics g)` is called. If you override it, you can decide yourself what the component should look like. Otherwise it will be painted with the default implementation.

Comment: @Kayaman so better way is to use this method extend JPanel and then paint component

Comment: Well you'll pretty much have to extend `JPanel` anyway if you intend to do any decent drawing. I outlined a suitable approach in the second paragraph.